# trying to get my image fade to work

Tags: javascript

```
var fade = 1;

function fadeit() {
    if (fade < 4500) 
        fade++
    else 
        fade = 1
    setTimeout("fadeit()", 100)
}

function fader() {
    fadeit()
    if (fade < 3500) 
        document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity = "0.4";
    else if (fade < 500) 
        document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity = "0.1";
    else 
        document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity = "1.0";
}
```

I am trying to get this code to work so that it will fade the image at different times.

Comment: You have error in your code: `setTimout` should be `setTimeout`.

Comment: thanks never noticed that, although it still dosen't work

Comment: The element fades only if fader in constantly called in this way.

Comment: You shouldn't pass a string to `setTimeout` for the same reason that `eval` is bad.

Comment: The second branch of your `fader()` logic will never be executed. If `fade < 500` is true, then `fade < 3500` will also be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually do the fading on each call to `fadeit`. All you're doing is running up the count. Also, the logic of your `if...else if...else` was wrong. The first condition will always be true whenever the second condition is true, so the second branch will never be taken. I've rewritten it here:

```
var fade = 1;

function fadeit() {
    if (fade < 4500) {
        fade++
    } else {
        fade = 1
    }
    doFade();
    setTimeout(fadeit, 100)
}

function fader() {
    fadeit()
}

function doFade() {
    if (fade < 500) 
        document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity = "0.1";
    else if (fade < 3500) 
        document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity = "0.4";
    else 
        document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity = "1.0";
}
```

Note that this will continuously cycle through the fade-in (which is what your original code was trying to do). If you want to fade-in once and be done with it, you could rewrite it as:

```
var fade = 1;

function fadeit() {
    if (fade < 4500) {
        fade++
        doFade();
        setTimeout(fadeit, 100)
    }
}

function fader() {
    fade = 1;
    fadeit()
}
```

Comment: Also, change `setTimeout("fadeit()", 100)` to `setTimeout(fadeit,100)`

Answer (score 2):

I would use JQuery to achieve that instead of writing your own JavaScript (it may not be cross platform)

Have a look at the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` function in Jquery

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 1):

I think  `setTimout("fadeit()", 100)`  should be  `setTimeout("fader()", 100)`.  Otherwise `fader` is never called ...

And you probably want to stop fading at some point.  The way you had it it would fade all the way in, then restart when the counter hit 4500.   Do something like this to prevent looping until you specifically call `fadeit` again:

```
function fadeit() {
    if (fade < 4500) {
        fade++
        setTimeout("fader()", 100)
    }
    else 
        fade = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calling the wrong method on loop ... change

```
setTimout("fadeit()", 100)
```

to

```
setTimeout("fader()", 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fade=1

function fader()
{
if (fade<4500) { fade++; }
else { fade=1; }
var op=1;
if (fade < 3500) { op=0.4; }
else if (fade < 500){ op=0.1; }
document.getElementById("showone").style.opacity=op;
//this is a loop i don't know if is the correct behaviour
setTimeout("fader()",100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are going for a pure javascript approach then might have to think about IE concerns etc..

This article describes it a bit better '[javascript fade](http://www.lateralcode.com/javascript-fade-effect/)'.

```
function fade( elem, time )
{
  var startOpacity = elem.style.opacity || 1;
  elem.style.opacity = startOpacity;

  (function go() {
    elem.style.opacity -= startOpacity / ( time / 100 );

    // for IE
    elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + elem.style.opacity * 100 + ')';

    if( elem.style.opacity > 0 )
        setTimeout( go, 100 );
    else
        elem.style.display = 'none';
   })();
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HCzJj/